# Dumping the content of a Toner Reset Chip using an Arduino UNO through I2C

Tags: identification, i2c, reverse-engineering

I am trying to dump the content of this Toner Reset Chip using an Arduino UNO. I read a lot about these chips and the most intriguing with this one is that it only has GND, CLK and DATA pins. There is no VCC pin. I went and bough a 3rd party reset chip to analyze its layout etc., but also, no luck.

I used multiple I2C scanning libraries to get the address of the chip but no luck. Is there anything I got wrong?

The dark green one is the original Samsung Toner CRUM chip for the CLT-404 cartridge. the one with the light green PCB mask is the 3rd party one.

[image]
[image]
On the Samsung one, the marking on the chip are the following:
[image]

Comment: There are pretty easy ways to harvest VDD from the clock and data lines, and the double diode SOT23 and the on-board capacitors are how that's accomplished. I'm not sure why you're convinced that the data protocol is I2C, as it could be something else or custom for this application. Get a logic analyzer or oscilloscope and see what clock and data look like...

Comment: Perhaps these pages could provide you with some more information:
[Link1](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32809161175.html)
[Link2](https://dutch.alibaba.com/product-detail/compatible-toner-reset-chip-for-samsung-404-sl-c430-sl-c430w-sl-c480-sl-c480w-sl-c480fn-printer-chip-resetter-60368477970.html)

Comment: From what I can infer of the circuit with a blue PCB, the pinout of the chip does look like that of a standard i2c EEPROM. How did you connect it when you used the i2c scanner? What pull-up resistors did you use?

Comment: Both boards look wired to harvest power from CLK. The green PCB looks like it has a microcontroller instead of an EEPROM, and the extra pads connect to it for debugging or programming. This might be faking an EEPROM that automatically resets the page count.

Comment: I did not use pull-up resistors. What values do you recommend ?

Comment: Can you please suggest a wiring schematic to hook up the pull up resistors?

Comment: Why not solve the problem of reset the analog way? Replace the 56 ohm resistor with a small fuse or another R. [Ref](https://youtu.be/MSPsVQdUr5M)

Comment: @Lilo you must pull up both SDA (DATA) and SCL (CLK) to VCC. Try low-ish values, maybe 1 kOhm to 3 kOhm resistors, since the boards will be drawing parasitic power.

Comment: It did not work with 1kOhm. I tried 33 Ohm and it worked. However, scanning resulted in a lot if addresses

Comment: 33 Ohm is way too low for I2C and may damage the chips. If the scanner is seemingly detecting a device at every address it's usually because of a problem with the bus.

Comment: Are you sure you connected the pull-up resistors to VCC? I recommend reading a tutorial on I2C.

Comment: I tried to measure the voltage of the scl and sda pins at the printer and both were between 2 to 3.5 v

Comment: @Lilo You may wish to edit your post, as the dark green board is actually blue.  Also, if that wasn't a simple mistake, you might want to take a vision test for Tritanopia, loosely known as blue-yellow color blindness.  It would make some shades of blue appear dark green.  I know this is absolutely none of my business (and you might already be aware of this).  I am only mentioning it because resistor color codes are a thing and being aware of a quirk in one's own vision like that might come in handy one day if you're debugging a circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. under some warm color lighting, it appears dark green but on cold white light it appears as blue.

Comment: if it is harvesting, you can expect that you will need to drive the lines that are being used to harvest from high for a while, maybe a few hundred ms, before you can do the comms. Put a scope on Vcc on the chip and check that that is OK first. Pullups are going to be on the high side in such a situation, to reduce current drain, and the comms probably won't take that long. The lowest I've seen in use on I2C is about 470R, in this case I'd expect at least 10 times that.

Comment: And I'd start by tracing a circuit. It could be that the pullups are already on the board.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the signal using a logic analyzer; the signal doesn't look like I2C. Basically, I2C pulls high at no communication, but the DATA and CLK are low, no start condition, no stop condition.